# How to know when WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is required

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am upgrading my Android app's Target SDK Version to 23 (Android M) which has the new Runtime permissions (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). My app has declared [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in its manifest, which must now me requested at runtime. Of course, I'd like to only request it when necessary.

I have an abstraction for different storage types, one implements local storage through normal File I/O (not the Android Content Provider stuff). In this class, I get a file path (like /mnt/sdcard/... or /data/data/...) and before accessing that file (read and write mode), I want to check if I have to call `RequestPermissions` for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

So the question is: What's the safest and simplest way to determine whether a file can be read and written without that permission (e.g. because it's inside getExternalFilesDir()) or not?

Comment: "In this class, I get a file path" -- where exactly is this path coming from? If it coming from elsewhere in your code, then you know whether it is on external storage wherever you are creating the path. If the path is coming from outside of your app (e.g., `Uri` on an `Intent`), then IMHO you are best served by asking the user for permission before you might receive such a path, such as on the first run of your app.

Comment: both ways are possible: paths may be created inside the app, but I'm also opening files from Intents. Furthermore, I have to deal with paths which have been used in previous versions of the app and are stored in shared preferences. I certainly can't ask all users because many users don't use any local storage but only cloud storage. But I can ask the first time they use any local file which is not in the app's internal directory. I was hoping there's a better solution.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am trying to update my app for API 23 and have the same issue, how can I tell if a path is an external path?

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) that you only have to ask for [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) when your application needs to write to external storage.
But:

> Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to
>   read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by
>   `getExternalFilesDir(String)` and `getExternalCacheDir()`.

First of all I recommend you to avoid requesting permissions using `Intent`s, because it's a best practice and improves a lot the user experience.

If you can't use an `Intent` to avoid writing with your app, and you know that some day the user will have to write externally, I think the better would be to ask for the permissions the first time the user takes the "write in external storage" path.

As far as I know, in API23 you only have to ask for permissions once, so I think the easyest way would be to ask for the permissions at the first time that the user needs the functionality, I think that then when he'll execute it again, permissions would remain accepted. You can check your granted permissions with the procedure shown [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check).

[Here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html#perms-vs-intents) you can read:

> The user is prompted to give permission once, either at run time or at
>   install time (depending on the user's Android version). After that,
>   your app can perform the operation without requiring additional
>   interaction from the user. However, if the user doesn't grant the
>   permission (or revokes it later on), your app becomes unable to
>   perform the operation at all.

Comment: The idea of the new permission system is that the permissions are not requested until they are really used. Chances are good that many users will never have to request that permission because there are many other option for storage locations in the app (e.g. cloud storage). For these reasons, I won't ask every user to grant that permission.

Comment: Ok then you know the answer, only ask for the permission when the user takes the external storage path, isn't it? Ask how the user want to store the data and then ask for the permissions or not.

Comment: what is "the external storage path"? Assume you have any local file path. When exactly is the permission required?

Comment: What I mean is you will be able to know where the user wants to store the data. So when you need to write in getExternalFilesDir() for example at the first time ask the permissions